# What are the method arguments in some ruby on rails functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for example text_field on https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field is documented text_field(object_name, method, options = {}) public. I am unable to find anything on what method is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method argument is in fact the attribute of your model.
You have an example:

```
text_field(:post, :title, size: 20)
# => 
<input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="20" value={@post.title}"/>
```

So in this case, :post is the model, and :title is the method (or your attribute you want to set).
This way, it will set params[:post][:title] to whatever you type in the text field.